# C pointer strangely self incrementing into unkown value during execution

Tags: c, multithreading, redhat

I'm facing an error due to "pointer corruption" in my program.
Here's the faulty code that's leading to a crash.

```
list_ptr = list_head;

while(list_ptr)  {

    printf("The value of list ptr is now %p\n", list_ptr);
    //do something;

    list_ptr = list_ptr->next;

    printf("After increment, the value of list ptr is now %p\n", list_ptr);

}
```

Now, when I execute the program, I got the following output by the end of the list:

```
..
..
..

The value of list ptr is 0x74c770
After increment, the value of list ptr is 0x6da280
The value of list ptr is 0x6da281
After increment, the value of list ptr is 0xce00000000006e80
```

The value of list ptr is 0x6da280 by the end of one iteration but its changed to 0x6da281 by the time the next iteration starts. After this an attempt to access ptr->next seems to be returning the value 0xce00000000006e80 which is not a value pointer.

This is a multi threaded program and the list pointer is accessed by two other threads. But I'm using mutex locks at each of these accesses.

I tried running the program in a similar setting again but could not get the same error. However its still crashing inside the same loop. My guesses are that the pointer is still getting corrupted but this time its after I print the value.

Any suggestions?

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.1.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
I too suspected a race condition initially but now I'm sure that this is not the case. Although the variable under question is accessed inside two other threads, they're all using proper mutex locks.

This is a multi-threaded program that forks about 500 children. The problem appears somewhere after the 470th fork(It hasn't been consistent). See the list under question is a global data structure maintained by the parent to track its children. Every time a new child is forked, the corresponding entry is added to this list. Somewhere after the 470th fork, when the list is traversed, there seems to be a corruption.

My colleague suspects that this could be due to stack corruption. But we haven't been able to verify this yet.

Comment: Paste more code. Is this traversal of the list under the protection of a mutex? Is the last node's `next` pointer supposed to be NULL?

Comment: Given that you've tagged this "multithreading" I'm guessing you have a race condition or simply undefined behaviour elsewhere causing this.

Comment: Can you please post the synchronization code?

Comment: @David Schwartz: Yes and yes. Sorry for not adding the code you asked for. The program is fairly complex and it'd take a lot of space to add all the relevant synchronization code. But I can assure you that synchronization is not the problem here.

Comment: Are you freeing up the malloc'ed structures when their need is over? Also in the case of free'ing of list entries, whose nodes inturn contains dynamically allocated data, you need to free the inner data first and then free the list node. Check how many malloc's you have and how many free's you have.

Comment: Also `list_ptr` is being changed by one of ur thread. Check which thread is setting the value of this. It would be better if you share the extracts of the threads.

Comment: You should check out Valgrind.  I sounds like either a race condition or a memory access error (if your synchronization really is correct another thread could still be writing to memory it shouldn't be).  Valgrind can help you find both of these sorts of errors (if you're using pthreads it can help find race conditions).  I would read through the documentation and start using it.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you mentioned that the auto increment of the pointer value. As awoodland said, I believe, it is because of saome race condition.

But the second problem, the list_ptr -> next, I think you have declared the pointer but never initialized the values. So some undefined garbage values are coming. (this is just a suggestion. If you give more explaining code, we can find the exact problem)

Comment: All variables have been properly initialized to NULL during declaration itself.

Comment: at first you initializing the pointers to NULL. but after calling malloc? so if you didn't the the line_ptr -> next will be some unpredictable garbage value. you better go through the code patiently once again. Most of the times it is been suggested to use calloc instead of malloc. because calloc initializes all the allocated memory to zero but not malloc.

Comment: Every time I call malloc, I'm immediately initializing the newly allocated memory using memset. So I dont think this is the issue.